# Utilizing a broken lamp socket

Tags: electrical, old-house, socket

I have this reading lamp socket which is broken for 20 years, home is also very old, but I am unable to put it for any good use; no one uses this lamp or will use it. Can I use it for any good use like a charging plug?[image]

Comment: Where are you located? Most answers here are US-based but we have some knowledge of other country electrical systems around.

Comment: Why not replace it with a new one after turning off the breaker.  Will be much safer and should not take long(famous last words).

Comment: But, yes, you could also replace it and/or the switch with an outlet (with the breaker off, of course.) Exact details depend on how it was wired; photos of the wiring of both would help us advise you.

Comment: @crip659, with surface mount wiring, more likely, "after removing the fuses."

Comment: @DrMoishePippik many houses in Europe employ surface mount wiring and plumbing, even though they're fairly modern. It's quite odd to us Americans, but it seems to be the way they roll over there.

Comment: @FreeMan, that's shocking, but it must be current practice ;-)